# conga template specific for some object like invoice

Tags: object, salesforce, apex, salesforce-communities

If i have conga template specific for some object like invoice then it should show those specific templates on that object.

When someone click on Send to sign there we need to see. So if we clicked from invoice then show invoice templates likethat